# iggrid edit row displaying duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am working on igGrid (infragistic grid) group by with edit row.
I have multiple rows in a group like below

[image]

When i am trying to edit the second row in a group, first row cell values are by default filling into second row. like below

[image]

I am trying to update cell values manually in editRowStarted event but its not working.

Unable to post code here as it is very much big with many iggrid events.

If anyone have idea about this, please share your ideas. Thanks

Comment: How do you set the id of the updated row? If the database Id of the row is different than the grid id and you do not take this into consideration you will have such problem. I had such problem :) Try to debug the update method with infragistics.lob.js included in order to see the exact problem.

Comment: We would still need to see some code in order to help you out in the best way possible.